# File with Multiple ISO encodings

Tags: sed, unicode, iso, character-encoding

I have an Arabic file with multiple ISO encodings; encoded in ISO-8859-6 and a few characters encoded in ISO-8859-1 (Because they don't have an equivalent in ISO-8859-6). I want to convert this whole file into utf-8. So, what I attempted to do is convert the whole file into ISO-8859-1 using `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t ISO-8859-1 fileip>fileop` and then to utf-8 using `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 fileop>finalfile`. However, the result is still not UTF-8 encoded Arabic characters rather just weird characters. Is there a way to unify the encoding and then get UTF-8 format? If not how can I remove the ISO-8859-1 without using sed, as it doesn't work on my utf-8 system.

Comment: Both encodings are in the same file? So how do you expect any algorithm to judge whether a given char should be treated with which encoding?

Comment: @Philippos then is there a way to only keep one encoding format in a file and remove the other?

Comment: Is it just a single file (then I'd just say manually type out the file name in UTF8), or do you need to do this on multiple files? If it's multiple files, how do you know if the characters are -6, or -1?

Comment: @dirkt They are multiple files, and the characters encoded in -1 are known to me.

Comment: So what happens if you convert directly from ISO-8859-6 to UTF-8? Can you still identify the characters that were in -1? (I'd assume they would appear as the characters which they are in ISO-8859-6...) Could you add a second translation step, e.g. with `perl` or something that can replace UTF-8 characters, to pick and fix those specific characters?

Comment: @dirkt direct conversion from -6 to utf-8 is not an option, I get an error when I try to do that and the conversion halts. Reason being is some characters that are represented in -1 cannot be represented in -6

Comment: So do two steps: first convert the -1 characters into something in a special format that is valid -6, with an escape character in front, or similar. Then convert to UTF-8. Then convert the special format back. (How many different -1 characters are there?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130543/discussion-between-m-a-g-and-dirkt).